# Regression model

Tags: regression, time-series, anova, arima, autoregressive

I'm analysing returns of funds and i have data on the following for 1000 funds.

- Returns in Period t
- Returns in Period t-1

I want to use a time series model to see how much returns have increased from period 1 to 2(b_1 in the following model). The model i had in mind is the following: 
$$
y_t = b_0 + b_1(x_t) + e_t
$$
Where $y_t$ is the returns in period $t$, and $x_t$ is the returns in period $t-1$.

I've been researching time series models lately and I found that if you have data like I do I need to find the:

Autoregressive order

Integrated order

Moving Average order

But can't  I just see directly that my model is a AR(1) model? Since I'm only using 1 lagged variable? Or do i have to look at graphs to determine the orders?

Thank you

Comment: If you know that that is your true model, then your AR order is 1, your Integrated order is 0 (you don't difference returns), and your moving average order is 0. You don't have to perform model seletion if you already have a very good idea what your model is. And yes, in this case you can use least-squared/regression to fit this model, estimating $b_0$, $b_1$ and the variance of your error.

Comment: @Taylor Thank you for your answer. Well, since i only have data on return in period t and t+1 for each fund. Doesn't that mean that it is a AR(1) Model? Or can it be a ARMA or ARIMA model aswell?

Comment: So your saying i could use a simple linear regression to estimate b_1? Will it not be unbiased since y_t and x_t is highly correlated?

Comment: @Taylor 
So your saying i could use a simple linear regression to estimate b_1? Will it not be unbiased since y_t and x_t is highly correlated?

Comment: An AR(1) is an ARMA(1,0) is an ARIMA(1,0,0) is the regression you wrote down. Your estimate for $b_1$ will not be unbiased. And it is precisely because $y_t$ and $x_t$ are correlated that $b_0 \neq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

The most commonly used technique to evaluate the parameters $p,q$ for $ARMA(p,q)$ models is unfortunately a brute-search over the parameter space. However, there is an objective score that a lot of people use to automatically select the optimal parameters.

This criterion is commonly called the AIC, Akaike Information Criterion, and is basically representing a trade-off between number of parameters in the model, and log-likelihood (how well the model fits the data).

The formal definition is 
$$AIC(k)=2k-2ln(\hat{L})$$
where $\hat{L}$ is the maximum likelihood estimate given the model with $k$ parameters.

source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion